# Using pubnub with corona sdk - basic configuration

Tags: coronasdk, pubnub

I have been using corona sdk for some time and want to begin implementing pubnub with my multi-user app.

I downloaded the lua-master zip file and unzipped it.  What files and folders do I need in my corona application director to begin testing?  - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## PubNub Corona Lua SDK

Get started by visiting:
https://github.com/pubnub/lua/tree/master/corona

The PubNub Data Stream Network for Building and Scaling Multiplayer Mobile Games.  Game state changes, player movements, location awareness and monitoring.

[image: PubNub Corona Lua]

Be sure to copy **`"pubnub.lua"`** into your Project Directory,

and check out the sample code in the 3.3 directory for complete code examples!

> `pubnub.lua` -> https://github.com/pubnub/lua/blob/master/corona/pubnub.lua

#### Initialize

```
require "pubnub"

multiplayer = pubnub.new({
    publish_key   = "demo",             -- YOUR PUBLISH KEY
    subscribe_key = "demo",             -- YOUR SUBSCRIBE KEY
    secret_key    = nil,                -- YOUR SECRET KEY
    ssl           = nil,                -- ENABLE SSL?
    origin        = "pubsub.pubnub.com" -- PUBNUB CLOUD ORIGIN
})
```

#### Publish

```
multiplayer:publish({
    channel  = "lua-corona-demo-channel",
    message  = { "1234", 2, 3, 4 },
    callback = function(info)

        -- WAS MESSAGE DELIVERED?
        if info[1] then
            print("MESSAGE DELIVERED SUCCESSFULLY!")
        else
            print("MESSAGE FAILED BECAUSE -> " .. info[2])
        end

    end
})
```

#### Subscribe

```
multiplayer:subscribe({
    channel  = "lua-corona-demo-channel",
    callback = function(message)
        -- MESSAGE RECEIVED!!!
        print(Json.Encode(message))
    end,
    errorback = function()
        print("Network Connection Lost")
    end
})
```

#### Unsubscribe

```
multiplayer:unsubscribe({
    channel = "lua-corona-demo-channel"
})
```

#### History

```
function detailedHistory(channel, count, reverse)
    pubnub_obj:detailedHistory({
        channel = channel,
        count = count,
        reverse = reverse,
        callback = function(response)
            if response then
                for k, v in pairs(response[1])
                    do
                    print( type (v) )
                    if (type (v) == 'string')
                    then print(v)
                    elseif (type (v) == 'table')
                    then
                        for i,line in ipairs(v) do
                            print(line)
                        end
                    end
                end
            end

        end
    })
end

local my_channel = 'hello_world'
detailedHistory( my_channel, 5, false )
```

Comment: Thank you!.  There were some missing files initially in the lua-master.zip but that was resolved.  I have a program that incorporates the elements above, but much simpler but I am not able to receive messages in the pubnub console.  I don't know if its Android or Corona specific.  I've opened another question on that issue.  - Again, thanks.

Comment: You are totally welcome anytime and remember to checkout our other SDKs and developer resources for PubNub and realtime multiplayer game development Realtime Software Development Resources http://www.pubnub.com/developers/